# Apply same point of view effects to all 3d models

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have multiple 3D models that users can switch between. My goal is to allow users to change the point of view using the default camera, save this change, and apply it to any other 3D model.

Problem:
When I apply the saved point of view to other 3D models, I don't get the same result in terms of rotation, orientation, position, transform, and camera field of view.

What I have tried is to establish a base point of view for each 3D model and apply the changes using the following logic:

```
sceneView.pointOfView?.rotation = savedValue.rotation - 
baseValueOfSaved3DModel.rotation + current3DModelBaseValue.rotation
```

I applied a similar approach to `sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation, sceneView.pointOfView?.position, sceneView.pointOfView?.transform, and sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.fieldOfView.`

This method works for some changes, such as zooming in/out or rotating in place like a 2D model. However, if the user moves the 3D model in any direction or rotates it like a 3D object, the effects are not the same.